# Get method parameters from WCF OperationContext

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm trying to get a specific parameter value from `OperationContext.Current` as part of a dependency injection binding. It appears that I can parse the `RequestMessage` as an XML string to see the parameters in the SOAP request header, but this seems a little hacky to me. For example, different versions of SOAP might use slightly different ways of encoding the message in XML, and I'd rather not have to manage these issues myself.

WCF is obviously parsing this information out and getting the parameter values set up, so it seems like there should be some method or class somewhere that parses the request message out into an intermediate data representation, where I could find the name, type, and value of each parameter that is provided. Does anybody know a clean way to get this information from the current OperationContext?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Can you provide an answer if you did?

Comment: @Fulvio: I never was able to. Instead, I ended up binding to a sort of wrapper implementation, which checks the current context lazily when a method is called. At that point, the OperationContext is active.

Comment: I have a different sort of problem where I was trying to retrieve a value from a SOAP header: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6421846/c-obtaining-a-value-within-a-soap-header-from-the-operationcontext

Answer (score 0):

You can get the parameters with a Parameter inspector.

Comment: I've already looked into parameter inspectors, but they won't do what I need. They're only good for logging or throwing exceptions. I need to be able to access the parameters from the context of a DI binding.