# Obtaining a value within a SOAP Header from the OperationContext

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, soap

I have the following code in `C#` that looks for an `apiKey` in the the following `SOAP` header:

**SOAP Header:**

```
<soap:Header>
   <Authentication>
       <apiKey>CCE4FB48-865D-4DCF-A091-6D4511F03B87</apiKey>
   </Authentication>
</soap:Header>
```

**C#:**

This is what I have so far:

```
public string GetAPIKey(OperationContext operationContext)
{
    string apiKey = null;

    // Look at headers on incoming message.
    for (int i = 0; i < OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.Count; i++)
    {
        MessageHeaderInfo h = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders[i];

        // For any reference parameters with the correct name.
        if (h.Name == "apiKey")
        {
            // Read the value of that header.
            XmlReader xr = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.GetReaderAtHeader(i);
            apiKey = xr.ReadElementContentAsString();
        }
    }

    // Return the API key (if present, null if not).
    return apiKey;
}
```

**PROBLEM:** Returning `null` instead of the actual `apiKey` value:

```
CCE4FB48-865D-4DCF-A091-6D4511F03B87
```

**UPDATE 1:**

I added some logging. It looks like `h.Name` is in fact "Authentication", which means it won't actually be looking for "apiKey", which then means it won't be able to retrieve the value.

Is there a way to grab the `<apiKey />` inside of `<Authentication />`?

**UPDATE 2:**

Ended up using the following code:

```
if (h.Name == "Authentication")
{
  // Read the value of that header.
  XmlReader xr = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.GetReaderAtHeader(i);
  xr.ReadToDescendant("apiKey");
  apiKey = xr.ReadElementContentAsString();
}
```

Comment: what is returning then? Have you debugged the application and the web service? Is the same data reached on the web service?

Comment: Try logging value of h.Name somewhere

Comment: I have added logging. See my update above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think your `h.Name` is `Authentication` because it is root type and apiKey is property of `Authentication` type. Try logging values of `h.Name` to some log file and check what does it return.

```
if (h.Name == "Authentication")
{
    // Read the value of that header.
    XmlReader xr = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.GetReaderAtHeader(i);
    //apiKey = xr.ReadElementContentAsString();
    xr.ReadToFollowing("Authentication");
    apiKey = xr.ReadElementContentAsString();
}
```

Comment: You will have to use something else, looks like your XmlReader is empty because OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessages has read everything out of XmlReader and it is empty. What properties are available in MessageHeaderInfo  type? when you do h. , what all do you see in intellisense, you will have to use any of those properties to get the desired result.

Comment: I had to use `xr.ReadToDescendant("apiKey");` in order for this to work properly. You lead me in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Ended up using the following code:

```
if (h.Name == "Authentication")
{
  // Read the value of that header.
  XmlReader xr = OperationContext.Current.IncomingMessageHeaders.GetReaderAtHeader(i);
  xr.ReadToDescendant("apiKey");
  apiKey = xr.ReadElementContentAsString();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a shorter solution:

```
public string GetAPIKey(OperationContext operationContext)
{
    string apiKey = null;
    MessageHeaders headers = OperationContext.Current.RequestContext.RequestMessage.Headers;

    // Look at headers on incoming message.
    if (headers.FindHeader("apiKey","") > -1)
        apiKey = headers.GetHeader<string>(headers.FindHeader("apiKey",""));        

    // Return the API key (if present, null if not).
    return apiKey;
}
```